# Abort Mac OS X Mavericks installation

Tags: macos, mac

I've tried to install Mac OS X Mavericks using Target Disk mode, but unfortunately for some reason the installer tries to install it on the source machine, even though I choose the Disk from the attached Mac. Now I know my data is still there, because I can browse to it in the Terminal, but I can't see a way how I can bypass the installer and boot to the old system again.

Any ideas?

Very appreciated!

Comment: if you have terminal access you could update the bootloader i can't remember what MAC bootloader is if it grub, grub update would do it

Comment: It's definitely not GRUB.

Comment: look sliek this is where mac bootloader is now /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi use command line editor in terminal and make sure it has the right /dev, im pretty sure there is easier way but it too long since i done i

Comment: This file is in some binary format.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which disk to boot to by holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> at startup. If your disk has already begun the installation of the operating system, you may not have a valid OS anymore and may need to actually re-run the OS X installer. The installer does not overwrite any user data, but if you can access the data, it wouldn't be a bad idea to grab a backup.